# How to make sleep window exponential in Hystrix

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, circuit-breaker

In my application I have requirement to make sleep window in Hystrix Circuit breaker as exponential instead of fixed time interval.

@HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "2000")

Is there any property i can use to make the sleep window exponential or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

No that's the only one used by the circuit breaker, see [the source](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/a8203446b90333f005c88cacf91a5dc8faf07c1c/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreaker.java#L259).